# How to install uwsgi-plugin-python with apt in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, uwsgi

I'm running a old openstack CI rlease Train on utuntu 20.04. In env setup phase, it try to install some uwsgi packages:
apt-get install uwsgi uwsgi-plugin-python uwsgi-plugin-python3 libapache2-mod-proxy-uwsgi

but it failed with uwsgi-plugin-python: E: Unable to locate package uwsgi-plugin-python

How can I fix this issue? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

uwsgi-plugin-python is not in the default repositories of Ubuntu 20.04. uwsgi-plugin-python has been upgraded to uwsgi-plugin-python3 and is provided by the universe repository in Ubuntu 20.04 and later.  To install uwsgi-plugin-python3 in Ubuntu 20.04 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install uwsgi-plugin-python3
```